# Virtualbox with Puphpet, how to get servername, username and password?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying understand where I can find the servername, username and password so that I can connect to a database using PHP.

In order to achieve a database connection, I have an old file containing the following piece of code:

```
$ConnDB = new mysqli("192.168.56.101", "dbuser", "123");
```

But this always seems to return: `Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused`

I am using virtualbox with Puphpet. The config file of Puphpet contains the following (YAML) code: http://pastebin.com/d4i9Ffht